# Ways to retain nonexistent WhatsApp number

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger, titanium-backup, nexus-5x

All this while, I've been using WhatsApp with an old cellphone number which is now defunct. I now plan to switch over to a new phone. This means that I'll need to freshly install WhatsApp, but the catch here is can no longer use the old number because it's going to try sending the verification code which is never going to reach. Any ideas how to go about this?

1. I will finally need to update the new number in WhatsApp.
2. Have to root the phone and move the titanium backup copy from the old device to the new one and gamble with it. I don't think this option is going to play out too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the [Whatsapp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000018):

Requirements:

- The number you wish to use (the number you will change your account to) must be able to receive SMS and/or calls and have an active data connection.

On the old phone:

- Open WhatsApp.
- Go to Menu Button > Settings > Account > Change number.
- Enter the number currently verified on WhatsApp in the old phone number box.
- Enter the number you want to use in the new phone number box.
- Complete the verification process.
- Create a manual backup by going to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chats > Chat backup > Backup.

On the new phone:

- Transfer your chat history from your old to your new phone.
- Open WhatsApp.
- Verify the number you want to use with WhatsApp

Important Notes:

- Your old WhatsApp account associated with the old phone number will be deleted.
- Be aware that the Change Number process does not automatically transfer your chat history or media to your new phone. ([How to manually transfer your chat history to your new Android phone](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921)).

Comment: Doesn't look like there is much of an option here to retain an account with a non existent number. Thanks for pointing me to the FAQ!

Comment: Yeah, it is a security mesure to prevent people to use phone numbers they don't own, because as you may have notice, you never register an account with which you could identify somewhere else. I guess it's one of the downsides to their 'easy to use' approach.