# Whether a new user of my old number can see my old WhatsApp messages?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

I was using WhatsApp with my mobile number since last 1 year. Suddenly the number got deactivated due to no call/messages for long days. However, I got to know that the same number has been allotted to another person-B.

Now I am wondering whether the person-B can be seeing my old WhatsApp messages those I had 1 year before attached to the same number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They cannot see your messages because they would not be able to sign into your account. Without your password and/or physical access to your phone where your messages are saved there is no way they will be able to access your messages.

An entirely new account can be created for the new owner of that number, but it is separate from your old account and does not have access to your old messages.

Comment: There is an important note: If people don't realize that you have a new number, the new account / old number might get messages which were written for you. It happened to me. I could still see the old messages that my friend has received and the new messages that the stranger received - in the same chat.

Answer (score 2):

I had asked something along the same lines (although not identical) just a few days ago. [Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148785/ways-to-retain-nonexistent-whatsapp-number/148793#148793)

Whatsapp stores messages locally in your phone's internal storage under Whatsapp/databases/ <<*.crypt12>>

Apart from this, the latest message backup will be stored in your google drive. (This is only if you have enabled the option to store a backup on your google drive)

So in essence, there is no way the person with your old number can gain access to your previous chat history.

What could happen is your current contacts, who *might* have your old number, would see that person in their whatsapp contacts.